# jquery mobile conditional cache

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-mobile, mobile

Is it possible to conditionally cache a page with jquery mobile?

For example, the data on the page should be reloaded every time the page is navigated to from anywhere else on the site except when returning from a modal dialog called from that page.

I have only been able to get it to do one or the other, cache always or never.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it programatically call this function to cache your page.

```
// you can get the page from where the call is being transferred from    
var referrer =  document.referrer;


// Use this code to disable the cache
pageContainerElement.page({ domCache: false });
```

and before calling the modal dialog, you can call the method with domCache: true

```
// Use this code to cache the page
pageContainerElement.page({ domCache: true });
```

Comment: Great, I will try this on Monday, I will accept it as the answer as soon as I test it out. Thanks.